# Ionic icon for fax machine

Tags: ionic-framework, icons, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need a Ionic icon for fax machine. The output will be a little fax with a fax number beside it, in the same way my `class="ion-android-call"`below shows an icon

my code is

```
<ion-list>
    121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
    Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
    HONG KONG<br>
    <ion-icon class="ion-android-call">: +852 1234 5678<br>
    <ion-icon class="ion-fax">: +852 8765 4321<br>
    : 
</ion-list>
```

hoever I'm unable to create this icon and the documentation doesn't seem to mention faxes at all. I've tried every configuration like `class="ion-fax"`,`class="ion-facsimile"`etc but no dice. Does Ionic support fax icons?

*Note: Facsimile machines, or "faxes" are machines from ancient times that transmit documents. The output typically prints to paper - see https://youtu.be/UlEFqR4SaVA?t=1m2s for how faxes are set to revolutionise teleworking*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually `class="icon ion-printer"` I was looking for the whole time. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the links for ion icons

1.[ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/ionicons/)

2.[ion icons](http://ionicons.com/)

we simply cannot use `ion-fax` etc.. we have to use icons provided by ionic team. Search for your required icon and if it is not available you can customize icon something like this.

in **.html** file,

```
<ion-icon name="fax"></ion-icon>
```

in **.scss** file,

```
.ion-ios-fax,
.ion-md-fax {
  content: url(https://maxcdn.icons8.com/ultraviolet/PNG/20/Household/fax-20.png);
  width: 24px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 6px 4px 2px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```